# win32 api edit control and keyboard accelerator

Tags: c, winapi, keyboard

I am writing a simple notepad editor (customized to suit some extra functionality) in win32 api. The edit control fills up the application area and takes focus at all times. I also need to handle some keyboard commands like Ctl-S. So I use a keyboard accelerator table in the usual way to define the Ctl-S key and in my message loop I have TranslateAccelerator

```
while (GetMessage(&Msg,NULL,0,0)>0)
   {
   if (!TranslateAccelerator(Msg.hwnd,HAccel,&Msg))
      { TranslateMessage(&Msg); DispatchMessage(&Msg); }
   }
```

Now my problem is that since the Edit window always has focus, when the user types Ctl-S I dont get a WM_COMMAND message at all. (I understand that the HIWORD of wParam will become 1 for keyboard accelerator, but that's not a problem here).

```
 case WM_COMMAND:
      switch (LOWORD(wParam))
         {
         ...
         case ID_CTL_S_PRESSED: {My code here} break;
         ...
         }
```

If I try the code with no Edit control then I do get the WM_COMMAND message above. So how do I go about getting the WM_COMMAND message for a keyboard accelerator when an edit control always has focus?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first parameter to [`TranslateAccelerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646373.aspx) is documented as:

> A handle to the window whose messages are to be translated.

This is misleading and not entirely correct. The section about [Processing WM_COMMAND messages (Using Keyboard Accelerators)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646337.aspx#wm_command) is more to the point:

> When an accelerator is used, the window specified in the TranslateAccelerator function receives a WM_COMMAND or WM_SYSCOMMAND message.

To fix your issue, replace the call to `TranslateAccelerator` with the following:

```
if (!TranslateAccelerator(hwndMain,HAccel,&Msg))
```

Replacing `Msg.hwnd` with the window handle to your main window will direct the `WM_COMMAND` message where you want it.

Comment: Thanks Hans. It works. I cant believe how simple the answer is and how I could fall into such a nasty trap!

Comment: @AmbarChatterjee Would you please mark this answer as accepted just to keep the records tidy?  (You will also get a few reputation points :) ).  Thanks!

Comment: Done! I was having trouble to locate the tick mark that changes from gray to green to mark an answer as accepted.